# base class pointing to inherited class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance, base-class

I have an inherited class which i would like to point to from the base class. Example below

```
class Base
{
    inherited* test;
};

class inherited: Base
{
};
```

the purpose of this is so that the base class (a character) contains a linked list of the inherited class (items)

ps apologies for any mistakes, i'm new to this site

Comment: In your example, the class `inherited` is not derived from the class `Base`? Have you looked at the difference between [inheritance, composition, aggregation](http://enoshtechdiary.blogspot.no/2012/04/composition-vs-aggregation.html)?

Comment: I assume the OP simply left out the ` : public Base` or whatever the language's equivalent semantics are.

Comment: my mistake yes it is supposed to be inherited, i will edit the question thanks

Comment: What language would this be? C++? A language tag is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible to trick the compiler into accomplishing this, but it's most certainly bad OOP design. If all you want to do is be able to store an instance of the `inherited` class but can treat it like the `base` class, then you can simply make `inherited* test` a `base* test` and it will accept pointers to either `inherited` or `base` (or any other subclass of `base`).

If you actually want `base` to treat that instance as `inherited`, you need to rethink your class hierarchy because you don't actually have an inheritance tree here.

Comment: I have edited the question to involve the inheritance syntax. So what you are saying is that using `Base* test;` instead of `inherited* test;` it will allow me to point to any inherited classes?

Comment: Yep. That's the whole point of [*polymorphism*](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/)

Comment: A note: if you use `: Base`, it will make all of `Base`'s methods private. You want `: public Base`.

Comment: Also please accept the answer if it met your needs (press the little checkbox next to it)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to go about what you are trying to a achieve but be careful not do access the derived class in the base class constructor.

```
class inherited; // foward declaration

class Base
{
public:
    Base(inherited* test_): test(test_)
    {
        // DO NOT access test in this constructor.
    }
    
    inherited* test;
};

class inherited: public Base
{
public:
    inherited(): Base(this)
    {
    }
};
```